# Can one NPS server be used for multiple authentication purposes

Tags: multi-factor-authentication, radius, nps

I have an NPS server which is configured to let company devices to connect to a bunch of Unifi AP's. Then I have a second NPS server which is configured to require Azure MFA when connecting to RDP sessions from outside the company network (2 defined RADIUS clients). Is there a way to consolidate the two servers? If you, any hint on how the setup with the policies can be done?

Thanks in advance
Na Wick

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not, see this quote from one of the docs:

> "Once you enable MFA for a RADIUS client using the NPS extension, all
> authentications for this client are required to perform MFA. If you
> want to enable MFA for some RADIUS clients but not others, you can
> configure two NPS servers and install the extension on only one of
> them."

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension